# AttributeError: 'Adam' object has no attribute 'get_weights'

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am pretty new to tensorflow Keras and there is a Problem Running Cross Validation that I could not fix. It all worked before I installed featurewiz (conda install -c conda-forge featurewiz).

from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_validate, cross_val_score
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier

estimator = KerasClassifier(model, epochs=500, batch_size=10) #, verbose = 0
kfold = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)
results = cross_validate(estimator, X, y, cv=kfold, scoring=['accuracy', 'precision_weighted', 'recall_weighted', 'f1_weighted'], return_train_score=True)

print(results)

Error:

```
WARNING:absl:Found untraced functions such as _update_step_xla while saving (showing 1 of 1). These functions will not be directly callable after loading.

INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: ram:///var/folders/c4/ywdtx99d1vl0ptsg1fy494_40000gn/T/tmpsuvxkjb9/assets

INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: ram:///var/folders/c4/ywdtx99d1vl0ptsg1fy494_40000gn/T/tmpsuvxkjb9/assets

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Empty                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/tensorflow-test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:862, in Parallel.dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    861 try:
--> 862     tasks = self._ready_batches.get(block=False)
    863 except queue.Empty:
    864     # slice the iterator n_jobs * batchsize items at a time. If the
    865     # slice returns less than that, then the current batchsize puts
   (...)
    868     # accordingly to distribute evenly the last items between all
    869     # workers.

File ~/tensorflow-test/env/lib/python3.8/queue.py:167, in Queue.get(self, block, timeout)
    166     if not self._qsize():
--> 167         raise Empty
    168 elif timeout is None:

Empty: 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 6
      4 estimator = KerasClassifier(model, epochs=500, batch_size=10) #, verbose = 0
      5 kfold = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True) #seed, damit shuffle gleich bleibt , random_state=1337
----> 6 results = cross_validate(estimator, X, y, cv=kfold, scoring=['accuracy', 'precision_weighted', 'recall_weighted', 'f1_weighted'], return_train_score=True)
      8 print(results)

File ~/tensorflow-test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:266, in cross_validate(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, return_train_score, return_estimator, error_score)
    263 # We clone the estimator to make sure that all the folds are
    264 # independent, and that it is pickle-able.
    265 parallel = Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=verbose, pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch)
--> 266 results = parallel(
    267     delayed(_fit_and_score)(
    268         clone(estimator),
    269         X,
    270         y,
    271         scorers,
    272         train,
    273         test,
    274         verbose,
    275         None,
    276         fit_params,
    277         return_train_score=return_train_score,
    278         return_times=True,
    279         return_estimator=return_estimator,
    280         error_score=error_score,
    281     )
    282     for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups)
    283 )
    285 _warn_or_raise_about_fit_failures(results, error_score)
    287 # For callabe scoring, the return type is only know after calling. If the
    288 # return type is a dictionary, the error scores can now be inserted with
    289 # the correct key.

File ~/tensorflow-test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:1085, in Parallel.__call__(self, iterable)
   1076 try:
   1077     # Only set self._iterating to True if at least a batch
   1078     # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
   (...)
   1082     # was very quick and its callback already dispatched all the
   1083     # remaining jobs.
   1084     self._iterating = False
-> 1085     if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1086         self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1088     while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):

File ~/tensorflow-test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:873, in Parallel.dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    870 n_jobs = self._cached_effective_n_jobs
    871 big_batch_size = batch_size * n_jobs
--> 873 islice = list(itertools.islice(iterator, big_batch_size))
    874 if len(islice) == 0:
    875     return False

File ~/tensorflow-test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:268, in <genexpr>(.0)
    263 # We clone the estimator to make sure that all the folds are
    264 # independent, and that it is pickle-able.
    265 parallel = Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=verbose, pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch)
    266 results = parallel(
    267     delayed(_fit_and_score)(
--> 268         clone(estimator),
    269         X,
    270         y,
    271         scorers,
    272         train,
    273         test,
    274         verbose,
    275         None,
    276         fit_params,
    277         return_train_score=return_train_score,
    278         return_times=True,
    279         return_estimator=return_estimator,
    280         error_score=error_score,
    281     )
    282     for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups)
    283 )
    285 _warn_or_raise_about_fit_failures(results, error_score)
    287 # For callabe scoring, the return type is only know after calling. If the
    288 # return type is a dictionary, the error scores can now be inserted with
    289 # the correct key.

File ~/tensorflow-test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:89, in clone(estimator, safe)
     87 new_object_params = estimator.get_params(deep=False)
     88 for name, param in new_object_params.items():
---> 89     new_object_params[name] = clone(param, safe=False)
     90 new_object = klass(**new_object_params)
     91 params_set = new_object.get_params(deep=False)

File ~/tensorflow-test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:70, in clone(estimator, safe)
     68 elif not hasattr(estimator, "get_params") or isinstance(estimator, type):
     69     if not safe:
---> 70         return copy.deepcopy(estimator)
     71     else:
     72         if isinstance(estimator, type):

File ~/tensorflow-test/env/lib/python3.8/copy.py:153, in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    151 copier = getattr(x, "__deepcopy__", None)
    152 if copier is not None:
--> 153     y = copier(memo)
    154 else:
    155     reductor = dispatch_table.get(cls)

File ~/tensorflow-test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scikeras/_saving_utils.py:117, in deepcopy_model(model, memo)
    116 def deepcopy_model(model: keras.Model, memo: Dict[Hashable, Any]) -> keras.Model:
--> 117     _, (model_bytes, optimizer_weights) = pack_keras_model(model)
    118     new_model = unpack_keras_model(model_bytes, optimizer_weights)
    119     memo[model] = new_model

File ~/tensorflow-test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scikeras/_saving_utils.py:108, in pack_keras_model(model)
    106 optimizer_weights = None
    107 if model.optimizer is not None:
--> 108     optimizer_weights = model.optimizer.get_weights()
    109 model_bytes = np.asarray(memoryview(b.read()))
    110 return (
    111     unpack_keras_model,
    112     (model_bytes, optimizer_weights),
    113 )

AttributeError: 'Adam' object has no attribute 'get_weights'
```

I created a Tensorflow enviroment on my M1 Macbook following https://github.com/mrdbourke/m1-machine-learning-test.
It all worked, I got following results:

```
TensorFlow has access to the following devices:
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
TensorFlow version: 2.11.0
```

I also installed featurewiz, I am not sure if there are some Problems installing it (I did conda install -c conda-forge featurewiz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SciKeras doesn't work with TensorFlow 2.11. The TensorFlow team release a breaking change in a minor version bump (they removed the `get_weights()` method). It will be fixed in SciKeras soon: https://github.com/adriangb/scikeras/pull/287

Edit: that PR was merged so the new version of SciKeras (v0.10.0) should solve this issue.